# Java Azure Function with IoT Hub trigger is not starting

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-triggers

i am trying to trigger a java function each time my IoT Hub receives a batch of 64 messages (or whatever, the number is not important). I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij) to create the basic code, then i edited creating this function

```
public class Function {

@FunctionName("ProcessIotMessages")
public void processIotMessages(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "message",
                eventHubName = "samples-workitems",
                connection = "HUB-1544-DEV_events_IOTHUB") List<String> messages,
        final ExecutionContext context) {...Function Logic...}
}
```

The **connection** parameter is the IoT Hub connection string in formatted as event hub compatible endpoint (e.g. Endpoint=sb://iothub-hostname-blablabla).

I package and deploy this code with maven plugins specified in the guide linked above. The deploys works fine, i can see mi function up and running with no errors from the portal, the HUB-1544-DEV_events_IOTHUB setting app is correctly created with the correct connection string.

The only strange thing i notice in the portal is in the trigger blade. As you can see, cardinality is One, while it should be set to many, since i did not specify the cardinality parameter in the function. The default one is many according to this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs). This makes me think that i not being able to pass the correct trigger syntax.

[image]

Anyway, **the problem** is that this function is not starting either from my local machine or the portal. Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: `eventHubName = "samples-workitems",` - this looks a little strage, are you sure that's the right name? (`Portal -> your IoT Hub -> Built-in endpoints)`?

Comment: It's the name listed in`Built-in endpoints` as `Event Hub-compatible name`. In the Connection String the name is under EntityPath.

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked. That was a dumb error actually...my bad. Thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @evilSnobu posted in the comments, the problem was the event hub name. Just go to `Portal -> your IoT Hub -> Built-in endpoints` and find all the information to configure the trigger in there.